# Break string up and section to the end

Tags: regex, sed

I am using a sed command to find `/controller which is a word/action`

```
"href="/bdgp/bdgp-record-com1-form?type=R&year=<?php echo $year;?>&batchNumber=<?php echo $this->escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?> "
```

which changes the result like so...

```
href="<?php echo $this->url("bdgp", array("action"=>"bdgp-record-com1-form"))?>?type=R&year=<?php echo $year;?>&batchNumber=<?php echo $this->escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?>
```

This is the sed command I am using which finds the pattern like /anything/anything/anything

```
sed -i 's%href=\"\/\([^/]*\)\/\([^/]*\)?\([^/]*\)%href=\"<?php echo $this->url(\"\1\", array(\"action\"=>\"\2\"))?> \"<%g' changes.txt;
```

What I get though is this...

```
href="<?php echo $this->url("bdgp", array("action"=>"bdgp-record-com1-form?type=R&year=<?php echo $year;?>&batchNumber=<?php echo $this->escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?>
```

How would I extract out from the result the ?type=R&year=&batchNumber=escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?> and put it on the end?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if it will work will other inputs... but for given sample, you can simply use three `s` commands in this order: first change the first `?`, then change the first two `/`s

Comment: something like `sed 's/?/"))?>?/; s%/%", array("action"=>"%2; s%/%<?php echo $this->url("%'`

Comment: That's interesting! Some power in using sed oO. Only needed to work with it now but funny how messed up it can get without the knowledge oO! I'll try that now. It should be used opposite the other command, should it?

Comment: That worked quite well. I just need to know how to add it into my previous commands. None stop tweaking like oO. If adding this in should I use three `s` commands? First, change the string to use the method, then concat the? onto the end and then the rest?

Comment: Pleas give a **Clear Pattern** and **NOT** *I am using a sed command to find the string* then *and change it like so...* . You can describe want you want to match or want do you not .

Comment: Updated the question. Hopefully, it makes more sense now?

Comment: **NOT** | In the first string exactly what `string` or `controller`  should be matched, write the name of all them.; if you want someone can help you better

Comment: It's not an exact match I need you see. There are multiple links that I'm trying to change. So it's a dynamic approach I'm looking for. So for this bit the controller and action will be different and some links will also have attributes. The attributes section is the part I'm having problems with which is why I'm asking. I know nothing about sed but the last sed command I had did the job for most of the links except the attribute ones following a `?`